# Moving from one public int to another

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a "If checkmarked" it will stop the public override int it is in and go to another public int thus stopping the original int and running on the new called public int

```
Return 0;
Return 1;
return base.PreServLogin();
```

```
    public override int PreServLogin()
    {
        if (GetBoolSetting("NeedReg"))
        {
            Log("Registering first... Please wait");
            Registration();
            //STOP PreServLogin code and ONLY run Registration()
        }
        //once complete goes direct to ServerLogin if NeedReg isnt checkmarked
        return base.PreServLogin();
    }
    public override int ServerLogin()
    {
        return base.ServerLogin();
    }
    public int Registration()
    {
        Where I want code to continue and stop running PreServLogin into ServerLogin
        return base.Registration();
    }
```

Comment: What is an "if checkmarked"? I also don't understand "running on the new called public int". You talk about stopping ""PreServLogin code", but are you asking how to cancel the method execution, or what? Can you make your question clearer? I'm so confused.

Comment: Those are not  *public override int*s. Those are methods. It makes it much easier to understand what you're asking if you use the proper terms.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't very clear, but this might be what you want:

```
public override int PreServLogin()
{
    if (GetBoolSetting("NeedReg"))
    {
        Log("Registering first... Please wait");
        return Registration();
    }
    return base.PreServLogin();
}
```